# Redux-i18n accessing t() function outside React components, e.g. in action creators

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux-i18n

I'm using Redux-i18n inside my React components. Works as designed. Now, I have several business logic as separate functions within my action creator files. This includes additional error handling and validity checks. Some of them are displayed other are sent by eMail. At this point I know the user / recipient and want to show them the message / mail in their preferred language. I use templates in the backend of course, but I have certain attributes from the application I want to add and translate.

For this reason, I'd like to translate the messages in the action creators. Is there a way to access the translate literals handy like in the components with the `t()` function?

Answer (score 6):

In the components the recomended way of using react-redux-i18 is,

```
<Translate value="application.title"/>
```

and outside the method, like action creators, you can use,

```
I18n.t('application.title');
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. I'm using APSL/redux-i18n not artisavotins/react-redux-i18n. Do you have an idea for that package as well? TIA